# Ubuntu 22.04 software center loading forever

Tags: 22.04

This seems to be a question that has been asked years ago but I don't think there's an updated answer to the more recent Ubuntu release, and I am stuck with it...

Basically I installed Ubuntu 22.04, and the software center gets the 'loading forever' screen every now and then.

When I reboot the system and open software center, it loads ok. Checking updates also works. But after using the system for a while including putting the system to sleep and back up again, software center will stop responding. Whenever I search for anything in the 'explore' tab, or clicking on the 'updates' tab, it shows the loading screen forever.

Any solutions please?

Thanks

[image]